# Is there any way to get power armor to a settlement without wearing it?

Tags: fallout-4

I have two power armor frames in Sanctuary. I want to move one to another settlement. Do I have to put it on and walk/fast travel? Or is there some way to carry it? Also strongly related question but can be split off, if I buy a frame from a vendor will it just appear next to me and I have to go into it to move it or does it just sit in my inventory until I "equip it."

Comment: Not sure about the first part, but all the power armors that I have bought just appeared at whatever power armor workbench was near the vendor.

Comment: What's wrong with with putting it on and fast traveling? It doesn't take a huge amount of time or use up enough of a Fusion Core to be noticeable.

Comment: Loading times and sanity. Right now I only have 2. I imagine soon enough I will have more than 2. Fast Traveling 2 times per suit is a long time waiting.

Comment: @Reafexus what do you play on? Even on PS4, fast traveling seems to take like 20-30 seconds, at worst.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Power armour must be worn to move it (at least until the new GECK arrives).
Power armour frames do not go into your inventory. When you buy one, they will appear nearby and must be worn to move.
Power armour pieces do go into your inventory and are effectively in the inventory of the frame you transfer them to. When you use a Power armour workstation, you can modify, repair and equip all of the power armour pieces in your inventory, and the inventory of any Power armour Frame placed at that workstation.
With regard to djsmiley2k's comment about using companions, I'd suggest using your companion to move an additional suit of PA, if you need to move more than one suit at a time (so rich!!). Dismissing them and waiting for the suit to appear seems like an awkward approach, imo.

Comment: The last time I dismissed Nick, while we were standing in Sanctuary, telling him to go to Starlight, he exited his PA near the town line of Sanctuary. You could be in for a *really* long wait.

Comment: What do you mean by "so rich"? I've got about a dozen PA frames - about half of them fully-loaded - and I only maybe spent caps on one of them. That's not even counting the handful of "stolen" frames I took from Raiders and BoS. There's just that many out there to be found free for the taking.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get a power armour to a settlement that I can think of, is to bring a companion to that power armour, make them equip the suit, and then dismiss them sending them back to the settlement you want the armour at.

It'll eventually turn up there, empty.

Comment: They really just unequip it and leave it in some random place around the settlement..?

Comment: Note that equipping them, fast traveling, and then ordering them out of it at least has the advantage of only having to fast travel once.

Comment: @Yorik why is that an advantage to only fast travel once?

Comment: Have you had it turn up empty? When I dismiss a companion in power armor, they show up at the settlement wearing the armor.

Comment: Yup, empty, beside the house I have as a base. Took me a while to notice it as it was almost inside the wall.

Pretty sure it didn't show up right away either, but awhile later. As I thought I'd lost it.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Check the companion's inventory. They might have the parts. Chances are they got in a fight along the way (or while defending the settlement) and all the parts became fully damaged in the process. Also, for why it didn't show up right away: NPCs don't fast travel if they're not actually following you when you do. They just casually stroll to wherever they've been sent.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Power armor frames need to be worn by *someone* to be moved, but it doesn't need to be you.

Have one of your companions wear it, then dismiss them and tell them to go to the settlement you want the armor at.

They will show up at the settlement, still wearing the armor. I've tested this a few times, on the Xbox One. I specifically recall it working with Piper.

However, in most situations this would probably be less convenient than simply donning the armor and moving it yourself.

If your concern is saving loading screens, and you have a bunch of suits at one settlement that you'd like at another, then this could actually help in that situation:

- Go to the settlement your companions are at.
- Tell them all to go where the armors are.
- Go where the armors are yourself.
- One at a time, have them get in and then tell them to go back to the other settlement.

All that being said, there's really no need to ever deal with more than two frames, unless you like them as decoration. As a result, I've never bought a frame from a store, and can't say what becomes of it.

Comment: Any non-console option that doesn't have you or an active follower transporting the armor is going to be a bit risky. When they're not following you, NPCs don't just instantaneously jump between locations (it's possible exceptions are made for story-driven purposes, but that doesn't help arbitrary player-driven assignments). They actually walk the whole way. There's no telling what they may do or encounter during that trip, and it's hard to guess at how long it's going to take them.

Comment: @Iszi Yeah, that's fair.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes. With console commands.**

When you find a suit in the wild, open the console and get its ID. They're usually followed by [EE] or [EP], or you probably have the wrong thing selected. Use `disable` and `enable` to see if you've got the right ID. Be sure to (re)enable *anything* you disable or you risk breaking your save.

Write the ID down.

When you get home, or wherever you want it, open the console and type `prid (the suit's ID here, no parentheses)`. Now that it's your selected ID in the console, type `moveto player`.

---

I'm not sure how much this will preserve your sanity, but this is the only way I know of to move PA without *anyone* wearing it. The hardest part is finding where to click to get it selected in the console.

Fast traveling or using console commands are always going to be faster than using the GECK - unless I'm completely missing something here, it will still require restarting the game (or you know the console commands better than I do - the question's moot at that point, because there *are* ways to activate some mods while the game is still running, but that is way beyond my comfort zone).

`Moveto` should work on almost every item in the game, so that includes purchased frames. If all this *console/breaking my save* stuff scares you, then good, don't use it. These are some of the simpler [tricks to do in the console](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_console_commands) and if you're unfamiliar using it, I'd advise against doing so on your main save until you are. E.g., do not confuse `moveto player` with `player.moveto` (moves: it-to-you and you-to-it, respectively).